# SQL takes too long. How can I optimize this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

The issue with this query is that is too slow:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
      SELECT
         *
      FROM
(
            SELECT
               *
            FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                     *
                  FROM
                     (
                        SELECT
                           *
                        FROM
                           (
                              SELECT
                                 MIN(UPPER(MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME)) as MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_USER_ID ID,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_LOGIN_TIME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_CREATED_DATE,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_UUID,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_FIRST_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_UPDATED,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_CUSTOMER_UID
                              FROM
                                 (
                                    MSG_USERS
                                    left join MSG_ACCOUNT_USERS on MAU_USER_ID = MSU_USER_ID
                                    left join MSG_ACCOUNTS on MSA_ACCOUNT_ID = MAU_ACCOUNT_ID
                                    left join MSG_TENANTS on MTE_ACCOUNT_ID = MAU_ACCOUNT_ID
                                 )
                              WHERE
                                 (
                                    MSG_USERS.MSU_ROLE_NAME <> 'CUSTOMER_INTEGRATION'
                                    AND MSG_USERS.MSU_ROLE_NAME <> 'CUSTOMER_EXTERNAL_INTEGRATION'
                                    AND MSG_USERS.MSU_ROLE_NAME <> 'INTEGRATION_SUPERUSER'
                                    AND MSG_USERS.MSU_ROLE_NAME <> 'OAUTH2_CLIENT'
                                 )
                              GROUP BY
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_USER_ID,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_LOGIN_TIME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_CREATED_DATE,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_UUID,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_FIRST_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_NAME,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_UPDATED,
                                 MSG_USERS.MSU_CUSTOMER_UID
                              ORDER BY
                                 MIN(UPPER(MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME)) ASC
                           )
                        ORDER BY
                           UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) ASC,
                           ID ASC
                     )
                  WHERE
                     ROWNUM < 7
               )
            ORDER BY
               UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) DESC,
               ID DESC
         )
      WHERE
         ROWNUM < 7
   )
ORDER BY
   UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) ASC,
   ID ASC;
```

I am not sure how to optimize it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements for your tables; an English description of what your code is supposed to do; an `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your query; and **format your query** so that it is readable.

Comment: I think most of the nested sub-queries are redundant as you are repeatedly filtering on `WHERE ROWNUM < 7` and once you have done that once then there will never be more than 6 rows in the result set so doing it a second time with a different ordering is pointless.

Comment: Also, please add the execution plan for the inner select that has the joins, where and group by clauses.

Comment: The first thing to start with in the query optimization is a retrieval of **actual** execution plan (via `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` or more user-friendly `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor` that returns HTML as in the Enterprise Manager). Otherwise it is rather guessing because you do not what is actually slow, why  and what is really going on under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

In principle you do

```
select ...
from (((( ...
                              ORDER BY
                                 MIN(UPPER(MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME)) ASC
                           )
                        ORDER BY
                           UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) ASC,
                           ID ASC
                     )
                  WHERE
                     ROWNUM < 7
               )
            ORDER BY
               UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) DESC,
               ID DESC
         )
      WHERE
         ROWNUM < 7
   )
ORDER BY
   UPPER(MSU_LOGIN_NAME_SORT) ASC,
   ID ASC;
```

What is the purpose of this crazy chain?

You make `LEFT JOIN` with tables `MSG_ACCOUNT_USERS, MSG_ACCOUNTS, MSG_TENANTS` but they are not used in your query. So, why do you (left) join them? They have no effect, I would guess you can simply remove them from your query and then you even don't need the `GROUP BY` clause.

I assume your query can be reduced to something like this:

```
SELECT
   MSG_USERS.MSU_USER_ID ID,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_LOGIN_TIME,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_CREATED_DATE,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_LOGIN_NAME,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_UUID,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_FIRST_NAME,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_NAME,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_LAST_UPDATED,
   MSG_USERS.MSU_CUSTOMER_UID
FROM MSG_USERS
WHERE MSG_USERS.MSU_ROLE_NAME NOT IN ('CUSTOMER_INTEGRATION' 'CUSTOMER_EXTERNAL_INTEGRATION' 'INTEGRATION_SUPERUSER' 'OAUTH2_CLIENT')
ORDER BY ...
FETCH FIRST 7 ROWS ONLY;
```